# What theories or formulas are involved with velocity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, kinematics, friction, velocity

What theories or formulas are involved or can be added as background information in an experiment that sees a small toy car roll freely down an incline where the surface area is altered to cause more friction. 
Are there any theories that state why a specific surface will cause more friction or less friction and how it will affect the velocity of the toy car. 
What theories are involved with velocity or the influence of friction on velocity?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rotational motion theory, the kinetic motion theory, the friction theory, and added to further too in special conditions

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to say this but surface area is not proportional to the force of friction. Friction is given by the coefficient of friction (static or kinetic) multiplied by an objects normal force.
What may ne useful is the theory that the coefficient of friction is equal to the tangent of the angle at which an object starts to move on a plane.
Also something that you might want to watch out for is the difference between static and kinetic coefficient. The kinetic coefficient has a lower value than the static one. Many people get this wrong but in a car where the tires spin without slipping the friction is static so be sure to use the right coefficient.

Comment: by surface area i meant different surfaces such as wood, foil, carpet, bubble wrap, sand paper etc.